# How to select the td within a table with a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have run into a problem I suspect has a very easy solution but it is stumping me.  In the following code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnHide').click(function() {
        $('td:nth-child(1)').nextUntil(':nth-child(4)').toggle();

    });
});
```

and the html

```
<table id="tableOne">
<tr>
<td></<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How would I go about changing the javascript so it doesnt target all tables but just the one with the id='tableOne'?

Answer (score 1):

Add that table in the selector:

```
$('#tableOne td:nth-child(1)').nextUntil(':nth-child(4)').toggle();
```

Comment: I just redid the code and it worked perfectly. Instead of 'tableOne' i had 'tableone' in my code.  Thanks a lot!